# iCloud Keychain in Safari Requires Password

Tags: macos, icloud, safari, keychain

I'm running macOS 10.14.4 with iCloud keychain. Safari is asking me to use touch ID or password every time I want to fill-in credentials. That wasn't the behavior since lately.

I saw some articles which advice to resent login keychain password, but that option is not available in the current version of macOS.

Is that behavior is by design or something is wrong with my security configuration?

Thanks,

Gil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These changes are by design, introduced in Safari Technology Preview Release 66 and promoted to Safari in macOS 10.14.4.

> #### Password AutoFill
>
> - Automatically submit login forms when filling credentials with Password AutoFill
> - On MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, require authentication with Touch ID to fill passwords into web pages; this can be changed in Safari’s AutoFill preferences

https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/

Comment: I see the release notes, but the AutoFill preferences do not appear to have an option to not require authentication. Only option is whether or not to fill in passwords at all.

Comment: @David Maybe OP has a Touch Bar Mac

Answer (score 18):

On Mac OS 10.14.4, go to system preferences, select Touch ID. Uncheck using Touch ID for Safari AutoFill.

It will no longer require Touch ID to autofill passwords and reverts back to earlier behavior.

Comment: Please note that _this_ is the correct answer; though the accepted answer provides accurate background, its proposed solution/workaround _does not exist_

Comment: Any idea on how to do this without turning on TouchID?